# wxPython: wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW is called when entering a child control

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to bind events to increase the opacity only while the mouse is present over a window, however the opacity is reduced whenever the mouse hovers over a child control

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.SetOpaque)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.SetSemiTransparent)
```

Is there an alternative to `wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` which is does not trigger when hovering over a child?

Example:

Hovering over the button or text box causes the opacity to drop (as defined in `SetSemiTransparent`):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the OS which is triggering those events, not wxWidgets.

In the parent's handler for `wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` find if the current mouse coordinates are inside a child or out of the parent.

To test if a point is inside a window you can use `wx.HitTest`.

Example of the wx.HitTest

```
class SomeFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.SomeEventHandler)

    def SomeEventHandler(self, event):
        if self.HitTest(event.Position) == wx.HT_WINDOW_OUTSIDE:
            #Process some event.
            pass
```

See also:

- [HitTest enumeration](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.HitTest.enumeration.html)
- [Window.HitTest(wx.Point)](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.HitTest)

Comment: See also this [recent thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/R7aDoGD82TI) on wx-users for some more details.

Comment: @Ripi2, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It's still very odd to me that the `EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` triggers while the cursor is not `OUTSIDE` of the window but is simply occluded.

Comment: I had updated, this with links to the docs mentioned by Ripi2, but apparently I was "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Comment: @Colton Because I'm the author of this answer, I've approved your edit.